# Twilio "Clicking" & "Static" for Streams (Websocket)

Tags: websocket, twilio, twilio-api

We've been encountering an issue where there is a sort of "click" or static sound, almost like a microphone being slightly tapped, between audio clips sent over the websocket connection during a streaming conversation.

The code to send is pretty simple

```
                media_message = {
                    "event": "media",
                    "streamSid": stream_sid,
                    "media": {
                        "payload": base64_encoded_audio,
                    },
                }

                await websocket.send(json.dumps(media_message))
                self.logger.info(f"Audio sent over websocket to Twilio.")

                #TODO: change mark name 
                mark_message = {
                    "event": "mark",
                    "streamSid": stream_sid,
                    "mark": {"name": "testMarkLabel"},
                }
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(mark_message))
```

We're synthesizing a few clips (sentence by sentence) and sending them over in succession.  It seems to happen the most if there's no delays between sending subsequent clips - i've mitigated the situation by calculating duration of each audio clip before attempting to send another, and checking if we received a 'mark' event, but even this doesnt seem to eliminate the occurrence.

Any ideas? It doesnt have to do with the audio encoding or format - when i introduce an arbitrarily large delay between sending, the click goes away entirely.  I also tried fade in/out on the audio clips, did not help.

Comment: Where you able to figure this one out? I have the same problem when I use `ffmpeg` to convert MP3 into mulaw.

Comment: @AndrewK I added my answer below, see what you think

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up truncating the audio data to get rid of the clicking sounds.  Not exactly elegant but gets the job done.

```py
    # first convert to wav
    wav_audio_data = convert_mp3_to_wav(mpeg_audio)
    # then to u-law
    ulaw_audio_data = audioop.lin2ulaw(wav_audio_data, SAMPLE_WIDTH)

    # Then truncate based on formula:
    # Remove the first 100 milliseconds of u-Law audio
    # 100 milliseconds = 800 samples = 800 bytes at a sample rate of 8000 Hz
    ulaw_audio_data = ulaw_audio_data[800:]
```